# Racket strange (require ...) semantics

Tags: racket, rackunit

I have a Racket code:

```
#lang racket
(provide (all-defined-out))

(struct weather (name perspective temperature humidity wind class) 
#:transparent)

;;Exercise 8
;;Todo implement
#;(define (read-examples file-name)
  (file->lines file-name))

;;todo uncomment
#;(define examples (read-examples "examples.txt"))

;;Exercise 9
(define (add-example examples example)
  (cons example examples))

;;Exercise 10
(define (attribute which examples)
  (define command (eval (string->symbol(string-append "weather-" 
(symbol->string which)))))
  (if (null? examples) null
      (cons (command (car examples)) (attribute which (cdr examples)))))
```

Also test file:

```
#lang racket
(require rackunit "xalt2.rkt")

(define examples (list (weather "Day1" 'cloudy -5 60 'yes '-)
                   (weather "Day2" 'cloudy 0 30 'no '+)
                   (weather "Day3" 'cloudy 10 45 'no '+)
                   (weather "Day4" 'cloudy 20 60 'yes '-)
                   (weather "Day5" 'cloudy 30 80 'no '+)))

;;tests for Exercise 9
(define argument-for-add-example (weather "Day77" 'cloudy 39 87 'no '+))
(define expected-result (cons argument-for-add-example examples))
(check-equal? (add-example examples argument-for-add-example) expected-result "addind to list is not working?")

;;tests for Exercise 10
(check-equal? (attribute 'wind examples) null "")
```

it gives me strange error about struct functions not being defined, but i have required the file with the struct defined and used in the test file...
I do use Racket 6.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error occurs because you are using `eval` in the wrong namespace.

Recommendation #1: [Don't use `eval`.](http://blog.racket-lang.org/2011/10/on-eval-in-dynamic-languages-generally.html)

Consider writing a helper function that converts attribute symbols into accessors:

```
;; get-attribute-function : Symbol -> (Weather -> Any)
(define (get-attribute-function attr)
  (case attr
    [(name) weather-name]
    ....))
```

Or you could make a hash table that mapped symbols to functions instead.

Recommendation #2: If you must, *must* use `eval`, you need to make sure you're giving it the right namespace. Read the docs on [reflection and dynamic evaluation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/reflection.html), especially the parts about namespaces.